# Excel VBA to auto search specific website

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, macros

I'm trying to make an Excel macro that opens up IE< then goes to www.selectleaders.com, then enters a location in the location field (ideally one pulled from a cell in the Excel, not hard-coded in the macro), then activates the search field.

So far what I have is as follows, but I'm at a loss as to what to insert for the ??? to get it to work.

Any suggestions or tips?

```
Sub SelectLeadersSignIn()
Dim ie As Object
Dim location
Dim button
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("https://www.selectleaders.com")
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set location = .document.getElementById("?????")
    Set button = .document.getElementById("?????")
    button.Click
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
End With
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I normally right-click on the website and choose 'Inspect'. You can view the source and find the ids used within the tags that make up the page.

Comment: thanks.   Anything in specific I'm looking for?

The relevant section of the code is (I think):

    <input type="text" name="location" value="Enter Location" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Keywords'; }" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Keywords') { this.value = ''; }" class="text" id="location">

Comment: The `id=location`. So use `Set location = .document.getElementById("location")

Comment: That's one of the things I've tried and I get a "type mismatch" error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to fill in your question marks.

```
Set location = .document.getElementById("location")
Set button = .document.getElementById("btnContainer").Children(0)
```

`location` is straightforward and follows my comment. The submit button doesn't have an id, so had to find its parent id and then select it as the parent's child.

Not sure what you want to do with these elements now that you've identified them, though.

Comment: YAY!  that worked!  thanks a ton!!!! :)

(Is there something I have to do specifically to mark this as solved?)

Comment: Great. Looks like you did it with the green checkmark. Glad I could be of some use.